# How to ignore duplicate resource error during terraform apply?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to reapply my changes using `terraform apply` but when I am doing it again , it gives me error with resource already exists and stops the deployment .

Example:

```
Error: AlreadyExistsException: An alias with the name arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:490449857273:alias/continuedep-cmk-us-east-1 already exists
        status code: 400, request id: 4447fd20-d33b-4c87-891e-cc5e09cc6108

  on ../../../modules/kms_cmk/main.tf line 11, in resource "aws_kms_alias" "keyalias":
  11: resource "aws_kms_alias" "keyalias" {



Error: Error creating DB Subnet Group: DBSubnetGroupAlreadyExists: The DB subnet group 'continuedep-sbg' already exists.
        status code: 400, request id: 97d662b6-79d4-4fde-aaf7-a2f3e5a0bd9e

  on ../../../modules/rds-postgres/main.tf line 2, in resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "generic_db_subnet_group":
   2: resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "generic_db_subnet_group" {
```

Likewise i get errors with many other existing resources.I want to avoid/ignore such errors and continue my deployment .

What other way i can use from which I can restart my terraform resource deployment from where it is interrupted in the middle.

My terraform version is :
`Terraform v0.12.9`

Comment: Where are you storing state? Can you provide the state configuration sections and the full commands you are running? My guess would be a differed or missing state for the subsequent apply.

Comment: I would say importing the resource to the terrafom state is the way to go, see also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62654684/terraform-alreadyexistsexception-an-alias-with-the-name-arnawskmsxxxxxxxxxx
In addition you should try to find out why your state is not stored correctly.

Answer (score 5):

The errors are returned by the API the Terraform provider is calling.

Possible causes of this could be:

- you ( or someone else ) have executed your Terraform code and you don't have a shared / updated state
- someone have created them manually
- a Terraform destroy failed in a way that deleted the resources for the API but failed to save the update state

solutions depends on what you need. You can:

1. Delete those resources from your Terraform code to stop managing
   them with it
2. Delete those resources from the API ( cloud provider ) and recreate them with Terraform
3. Perform a terraform import of those resources and remove the terraform code that is trying to recreate them (NOT RECOMMENDED)
4. Use `terraform apply --target=xxx` to apply only resources you need to apply (NOT RECOMMENDED)

Comment: To me it sounds more like their state was not available for the apply. I think it warrants asking questions about the state to narrow down.

Comment: I'm trying to understand number 4.  Terraform docs for [`-target`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan#target-address) don't help much.  Quoting: "...focus its planning efforts only on resource instances which match the given address".  Does this mean that `-target` is to select a subset of resources?  Are there examples of how to use this flag?  Here's an idea, can Terraform provide examples? :D